# Change background color if position fixed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this simple navigation that was built to hide a fixed header when scrolling down. When you scroll up it will reappear for easy navigation. It works great! However, I need it changed up a bit and not sure how to accomplish this.

When the position is fixed at the absolute top of the page I need the header to be transparent. When the position is then scrolled down and then scrolled up a little. I need the background to be blue until it reaches the absolute top then again change to transparent.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VYPGyg

here is the jQuery in question:

```
var didScroll;
            var lastScrollTop = 0;
            var delta = 5;
            var navbarHeight = $('header').outerHeight();

        $(window).scroll(function(event){
            didScroll = true;
        });

        setInterval(function() {
            if (didScroll) {
                hasScrolled();
                didScroll = false;
            }
        }, 250);

        function hasScrolled() {
            var st = $(this).scrollTop();

            // Make sure they scroll more than delta
            if(Math.abs(lastScrollTop - st) <= delta)
                return;

            // If they scrolled down and are past the navbar, add class .nav-up.
            // This is necessary so you never see what is "behind" the navbar.
            if (st > lastScrollTop && st > navbarHeight){
                // Scroll Down
                $('header').removeClass('nav-down').addClass('nav-up');
            } else {
                // Scroll Up
                if(st + $(window).height() < $(document).height()) {
                    $('header').removeClass('nav-up').addClass('nav-down');
                }
            }

            lastScrollTop = st;
        }
```

Any help would be great!

Comment: can't you do it using css rules? One for when class exists, one without class

Comment: Is the below what you're looking for? Some of your question was a little unclear to me -- not sure if you need intermediate styles applied

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use your `nav-down` and `nav-up` classes, since they're getting added anyways. When you use CSS to handle styling, you're (usually) better separating concerns amongst various aspects of your software. CSS should usually handle presentation, except where it's functionality is limited or not programmatic enough (enter javascript).

For example, take your .nav-down class and adjust the transparency:

Updated codepen:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YPNOLM

Added some logic to your function:

```
 function hasScrolled() {
            var st = $(this).scrollTop();

            // Make sure they scroll more than delta
            if(Math.abs(lastScrollTop - st) <= delta)
                return;

            // If they scrolled down and are past the navbar, add class .nav-up.
            // This is necessary so you never see what is "behind" the navbar.
            if (st > lastScrollTop && st > navbarHeight){
                // Scroll Down
                $('header').removeClass('nav-down').addClass('nav-up');
            } else {
                // Scroll Up
                if(st + $(window).height() < $(document).height()) {
                    $('header').removeClass('nav-up').addClass('nav-down');
                }
              // the 100 can be whatever height you think it should be at
                if($(window).scrollTop() > 100) {
                  $('header').addClass('notTop')
                } else {
                 $('header').removeClass('notTop')                     
                }
            }

            lastScrollTop = st;
        }
```

And an opacity property:

```
header.nav-down {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  transition: top 0.2s ease-in-out;
  z-index: 1;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 25px 0px 0px 0px;
  opacity: 0.8
}
```

And:

```
header.nav-down.notTop {
  background-color: blue
}
```

Comment: Not sure exactly what you mean. The .nav-up is only used to hide the navigation bar when it's scrolling down. When the navigation is scrolled back up the .nav-down shows again. I agree I think I can just use CSS here and would like to do that.

Comment: Sorry if it's not clear; I'll try and clarify. Are you wanting to have three states (at the absolute top, just below that, and when scrolled down) or two? I updated the codepen with what I think you meant: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YPNOLM

Comment: See updated answer; it's not especially clean or as functional as I would normally prefer, but I don't want to get opinionated about your code; this should work *if* I understand you correctly

Comment: yes! That is exactly what I was looking for! If you have any opinions or advice to make it cleaner or better by all means I would love to hear!

Comment: Great! I can refactor the codepen and post some ways I'd streamline it. You can take them or leave them, but they'll be more functional and hopefully easier to reason about

Comment: Can't complain with free advice! Thanks Mark I would love that!

Comment: Sure; let me see what I can do